DBeaver tells me a specific column doesn't exist on a "ADD COLUMN" command. Why?
I'm trying to execute the following command:
ALTER TABLE taco
ADD COLUMN i_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN na_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN ca_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN k_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN cu_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN zn_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN fe_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN mg_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN se_mcg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN p_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
ADD COLUMN mn_mg FLOAT DEFAULT 0;

It runs and the columns were created, but I do not understand why dbeaver says these columns were not found? Isn't the premise of a ADD COLUMN command that the quoted column doesn't exists?
Additionally, even after the column was created, it keeps saying that while at the same time saying the mentioned column already exists.

I don't think this is relevant, but I'm running PostgreSQL version 15, and I'm using the trigrams and full text search plugins.

DBeaver isn't the database. It's a client appication that either displays database error messages, or tries to offer completion and error coloring using the information it has. The client tool won't know anything about schema/table changes until it reloads the schema information

I understand that. Sorry About the question then. I didn't know it needed to restart the whole application. When I invalidated the connection, the errors persisted. Thank you

The first message is that the column already exists. By the way, not a fan of this type of data model, it’s much easier to create a table with elements and link these elements using a foreign key. Currently even counting the number of elements in a taco is nearly impossible

You could, optionally, turn off the feature where it tries to be helpful (and sometimes fails): Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Code Editor > Query Analysis, but you will lose some nice dbeaver functionality. This is only relevant for the Column i_mg not found message. The first message SQL Error [42701]: is directly from Postgres and is legitimate. No need to apologize for the question. It's a common misunderstanding and a reasonable question to ask.

I didn't say restart the application. The application itself will refresh the schema information eventually. You can right-click on a database and select Refresh, or use F5

mcg and mg stand for microgram and milligram? If so, why these different scales? That makes it harder to work with. Just use gram, the ISO standard.

se is stored in mcg because that the level of magnitude this element is found in the samples in the industry the application is meant for. I agree using grams would be better, but we have so many data sources using the standard that it was not worth the change, actually we started using mg and changed to mcg later.

Also, the only way I got to make it work was to restart the application, f5 and invalidating/revalidating the data source was not working.
Also, thank you again, now I know how to differentiate SQL errors from DBeaver errors in the UI.

Wouldn't a table with elements linked by a foreign key to the food required more queries? I really like how right now we have average 15ms for text searches on multiple tables with a couple million lines in total.

Make your like easier learn to use psql and ditch DBeaver. Then you would be dealing almost directly with the database and would not have to spend time fighting the client.

Normalizing your data could make it faster. I also expect your queries to be simpler and less error-prone. You will have more flexibility, as adding a new element is just an INSERT instead of an ALTER TABLE and changing every existing query.
